# I have installed java and it is working, but when i try to retrieve Java home it shwing empty

Tags: environment-variables, java

I installed Java in my red hat machine and when I run `java -version`, it is showing my installed java version.

However, when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME`, nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Will print the value if it's set. However, if you didn't set it manually in your startup scripts, it probably isn't set. That's why it is empty.

You can set it up using (or equivalent)

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/jdk1.7.0_02/
```